# Reverse for 'url_name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error after redirecting on a form submit and I don't understand why it happens, I know that posts about this subject aren't missing but after reading dozens of them I'm still not able to fix this issue.

```
Reverse for 'commenting_room_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.  
1 pattern(s) tried: ['room/(?P<gig>\\d+)/(?P<name>[-\\w\\d]+)/$']
```

Here is what my code looks like :

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MessageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        ...
        save_it.save()
        return redirect(reverse('commenting_room_detail'))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^room/(?P<gig>\d+)/(?P<name>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.commenting_room, name='commenting_room_detail'),
```

template/**room.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'commenting_room_detail' room.gig.id request.user %}">...</form>
```

If someone could explain to me why this error is appearing on this specific code It would help me avoid this common error for the next times, because everything seems correct, thanks.

---

Update here I changed the url destination as shown on the answers below :

```
return redirect(reverse('commenting_room_detail'), kwargs={'gig': room.gig.id, 'name': request.user})
```

I still get this error, if the problem is the urls regex patterns how can I resolve this ?

```
Reverse for 'commenting_room_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['room/(?P<gig>\\d+)/(?P<name>[-\\w\\d]+)/$']
```

Comment: The `kwargs` should go into `reverse` not `redirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the required keyword arguments for that url to `reverse` in your view function like you did in your template:

```
return redirect(reverse('commenting_room_detail', kwargs={...}))
#                                                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: `return redirect(reverse('commenting_room_detail', kwargs={room.gig.id, request.user}))` like so ?

Comment: `kwargs={'gig': room.gig.id, 'name': request.user}`

Comment: Still having the same issue

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error message

Comment: Updated, see the post

Comment: The `kwargs` should be passed to `reverse` not `redirect`

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example:

```
# views.py
class commenting_room(View):
    pass

# urls.py
url(r'^room/(?P<gig>\d+)/(?P<name>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.commenting_room, name='commenting_room_detail'),

# in code

# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'commenting_room_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['room/(?P<gig>\\d+)/(?P<name>[-\\w\\d]+)/$']
reverse('commenting_room_detail')

# success
reverse('commenting_room_detail', kwargs={'gig': 123, 'name': 'test1'})
```

This is your error:

> Reverse for 'url_name' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['room/(?P\d+)/(?P[-\w\d]+)/$']

Args issue error:

> Reverse for 'commenting_room_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['room/(?P\d+)/(?P[-\w\d]+)/$']

Double check your url patterns.

Comment: Updated my post can you take a look at the post ? I tried as suggested

Comment: You put kwargs to redirect, but you need to put them to reverse.